# How can I get a traceback on function calls?

Tags: search, redirect, debug

I've been trying to make a search page, but I keep getting redirected back to the main site. I can't find anything useful in the log about why this might be happening. Is there a way I can enable some sort of traceback so that I can figure out what is causing this? What I'd like to do is see some sort of list that tells me the names of the functions being called, and the php files where those functions reside.

Comment: Have you tried using xdebug? What IDE/profiling tools are you using and what environment are you looking to trace on?

Comment: I'm not really using any IDE or profiling tools at the moment, apart from vim, php -l, and lots of reloading pages. The environment is a linux server. I just found out about the Debug Bar plugin, but I'm fairly new to this, so I'm not sure what I should be using.

Comment: Please add the code that is relevant to your question. You said "I've been trying to make a search page". If anyone is going to help you, please [edit](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/140925/edit) your question and add that code. This will be a starting point to help you

Comment: @PieterGoosen, I understand the need for code snippets generally, but the help I'm looking for here is not with a particular block of code, but with a general inability to debug code because I don't have a function backtrace. In other words, I have no idea what functions are being called which produce an error. If I had a list of the functions called, I might be able to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Use [Better HTTP Redirects](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-http-redirects/) to debug redirects.

Comment: @codearachnid, I apparently can't install xdebug on my Linux install, because of package version issues (it requires outdated versions of mySQL).